# How to update table data onclick same button?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#submit").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            uid = $("input[name='user_id']:checked").map(function() {
                    return this.id;
                }).get().join(",");
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                data:{"uid":uid},
                url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>hr/shortlist",
                success:function(data){
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        location.reload();
                    }, 1000);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr class="info">
            <th>Check</th>
            <th>Recruiter Id</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="user_id" id="uid1211120937" class="user_id">
            </td>
            <td>20181123091338</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox" name="user_id" id="uid1211092847" class="user_id">
            </td>
            <td>20181123091338</td>
        </tr>       
    </tbody>
</table>
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="short"/>
```

shortlist.php

```
$uid = explode(",",$this->input->post('uid'));
foreach($uid as $user_id)
{
    $data = array('shortlist'=>'1');
    $this->db->where('uid',$user_id);
    $query = $this->db->update('personal_detail',$data);
}
```

In this question, I have multiple checkboxes. Now, What I want when if I selected all checkbox then `shortlist must be 1 for all` will be updated and if I unchecked some checkbox then `uncheck checkbox value will be 0`. So, How can I do this? Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: Start by removing the `name="submit" id="submit"` and instead wrap in form tags and use `$("form").on("submit",function() ----` NEVER call anything submit  - it will hide a form's submit method if you ever need it

Comment: And `name="user_id"` should be `name="user_id[]" to make those checkboxes return as an array

Comment: It is not clear what you want. You can count the checkboxes: `$("input[name='user_id']:checked").length===$("input[name='user_id']").length`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find all checkbox state respect to userid.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var uids = [];

        $("input[name='user_id']").map(function() {
            uids.push({id: this.id, value: this.checked ? 1 : 0});
        });

        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            data:{"uid":uids},
            url:"<?php echo base_url(); ?>hr/shortlist",
            success:function(data){
                setTimeout(function(){
                    location.reload();
                }, 1000);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Now in **shortlist.php**

```
$uid = $this->input->post('uid');

foreach($uid as $user)
{
    $data = array('shortlist'=> $user['value']);
    $this->db->where('uid',$user['id']);
    $query = $this->db->update('personal_detail',$data);
}
```

Comment: Nice one @PraveenGupta